# What kind of assignmnet does the colon [:] represent in Python?

Tags: python

I just stumbled upon this python code:

```
br: str = "check"
```

This kind of assignment I have never seen.
I get that we make sure that the object *br* is of class 'str' in this case.

Are there any other benefits using the notation above?

Comment: for type hints see [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) , [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **annotation** for a variable.

Variable annotations are there to support third-party tooling, such as type checkers; the syntax is new in Python 3.6.

> Just as for function annotations, the Python interpreter does not
>   attach any particular meaning to variable annotations and only stores
>   them in the **annotations** attribute of a class or module

check more at: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep526